# Android correct MVC coding to display a shape

Tags: android, model-view-controller, android-canvas

I have recently started working with android in eclipse. I have to keep within the Model-View-Controller (MVC) structure.

My goal is simply to display a rectangle box on screen. What I have got at the minute is a application that has four screens (main menu and the three other screens linked to it). The box implementation is for one of these three screens (board)

board.java code

```
package com.example.connectfour;

import com.example.connectfour.model.Gaps;
import com.example.connectfour.view.ConnectFourView;

imports[..]

public class Board extends Activity {

    private Button btnExit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        connectfourView = new ConnectFourView(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.board);


        btnExit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent startMain = new Intent(Board.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(startMain);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

board.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#48D9AB">


        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Play"
        tools:context=".Board" />

            <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Exit"        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

ConnectFourView.java code

```
package com.example.connectfour.view;

import com.example.connectfour.model.Gaps;

imports[..]

public class ConnectFourView extends View {
    public ConnectFourView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMinimumWidth(100);
        setMinimumHeight(20);
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int width = Math.max(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = Math.max(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }


    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

}
```

I have tried the following code in board.xml file which I believe would bring it all together however when a insert this it my application sends 30+ errors to logcat.

```
     <example.connectfour.view
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Note: As this is my first android post I am sorry in advance for any missing/additional code. Thanks you

EDIT for TanjaV. errors i get in logcat (these all appear when the above  code is added to the board.xml file.

```
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.connectfour/com.example.connectfour.Board}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.example.connectfour.view.ConnectFourView
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.example.connectfour.view.ConnectFourView
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:503)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at com.example.connectfour.Board.onCreate(Board.java:28)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  ... 11 more
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ConnectFourView(Context,AttributeSet)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:660)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:477)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:475)
11-20 19:14:56.446: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  ... 21 more
```

Comment: What errors do you get? What's in your logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the answer. I was missing the below code in ConnectFourView.java

```
public ConnectFourView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setMinimumWidth(100);
    setMinimumHeight(20);
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me discover this

Answer (score 2):

You need the actual class name in your xml:

```
<com.example.connectfour.view.ConnectFourView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Has removed the problem raised by toadzky. I am updating my question now

Answer (score 1):

You got the package name wrong in your XML. It should be `com.example...` not just `example...`

Comment: well you may want to check your stacktrace, because the error is "ClassNotFoundException: example.connectfour.view". So what is the error now that you have the package name right?